# vcovCR() on a plm object not working within a function

Tags: r, plm

I have recently noticed that calling `vcovCR()` (from the `clubSandwich` package) on a `plm` object (from package `plm`) within a function doesn't seem to work properly.

A simple example to recreate my finding is listed below.

```
example.plm <- function(some.data, linear.formula, cluster.variable){
  require(plm)
  require(clubSandwich)
  model.output <- plm(formula = linear.formula, data = some.data, model = "within", index = cluster.variable)
  vcovCR(model.output, cluster = some.data[, cluster.variable], type="CR1S")
}
```

We now run the function on the famous iris data

```
example.plm(some.data = iris,
            linear.formula = "Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width",
            cluster.variable = "Species")
```

and end up with an error message that reads: `Error in eval(mf$data, envir) : object 'some.data' not found`.

However, running the same calculations, but not inside the function works just fine:

```
require(clubSandwich)
model.output <- plm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width, data = iris, model = "within", index = "Species")
vcovCR(model.output, cluster = iris[, "Species"], type="CR1S")
```

Am I missing something here? Why can the function be run just fine outside of another function, but not inside one? To confuse matters further, this problem does not occur when using an `lm()` object instead of a `plm()` object. In addition, if I remove the `cluster = some.data[, cluster.variable]` part from the `vcovCR()` call inside the function, it also works for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

It may be a bug in the following lines of the `clubSandwich:::get_index_order` function, which is called from within `vcovCR`:

```
envir <- environment(obj$formula)
mf <- match.call(plm::plm, call = obj$call, envir = envir)
```

It appears `match.call` is looking for your variable `some.data` in the top level environment, whereas it exists only within the scope of your `example.plm()` function.

Maybe raise a bug report with the `clubSandwich` package maintainer?